# Firebase session persistence in Express

Tags: firebase, express, firebase-authentication

I just started learning node, express, and Firebase and after digging around, I've decided to ditch express's express-session API and go with Firebase's authentication system.

I'm trying to build a simple app that can handle multiple user sign-ins with express but I'm lost on where and when to use Firebase functions. I know I need some sort of session on the client side, but I'm unsure how to implement it.

Below is what I want my app to do:

- Log in with user credentials
- Store user information in a session object
- Redirect to the dashboard
- Retrieve user details from session object

Here is what I have so far:

```
    app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
        firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
            .then(function() {
            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(req.body.email, req.body.password).then((user) => {
                res.redirect('/dashboard');
            })
                .catch((err) => {
                res.send(err);
            });

        })
            .catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log(errorMessage);
        });
    });
```

I've read up on Admin SDKs, authChange, tokens and client SDKs. I'm a total newbie at this and I'm blown away by all the information. I feel like I'm missing an onAuthChange statement, but I'm unsure where to put it. This is also a testing nightmare because my local server returns an error when I use persistence.

How can I use session-like objects in Express? What do I need to implement to make sure multiple users can use my app at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. There's no need to initiate sessions in the back end because Firebase functions create a session object in LocalStorage. Powerful stuff.